# Query failing on older version of MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi so I'm working on a project and it turns out the version of MySQL on the production machine is different to the version I have locally, this had led to a situation where queries that run locally, cause an error on production.

An example of a failing query is as follows:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) month
     , YEAR(date) year
     , SUM(distinct_totals.total) balance
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT totals.*
                     , trans_data.date 
                  FROM totals
                  JOIN trans_data
                    ON totals.trans_data_id = trans_data.id
                 WHERE totals.id IN (1085)
                   AND trans_data.date BETWEEN '2016-04-05' AND '2017-04-04' 
     ) distinct_totals
 GROUP 
    BY year
     , month
```

Which works fine on my local version:

```
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18
```

But gives the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'totals.*' in 'field list'
```

In version:

```
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.31
```

Is there any obvious reason as the what changes between versions has caused this?

Comment: `amounts.*` is not in this query. So where the error from? Is there any other related queries?

Comment: `DISTINCT totals.*,` is enough.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that now, do you know of any documentation explaining why it works in the new version and not the old. Just for my own reference.

Comment: Does my answer helped you. I have deleted it, all says its error.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'totals.*' in 'field list'

suggests that you have

```
select `totals.*`
```

somewhere in the query.  You need to remove the outer backticks or limit them to one identifier:

```
select `totals`.*
select totals.*
```